# unable to add account on target in ISIM 6.0

Tags: tivoli-identity-manager

I am trying to create an account by making an add operation thru manage operations column.  i have created add operation and its LCR on entity level (Account)

I am using extension (CreateAccount(person owner, service service, account account).  I have defined all 3 variables in relevant data and LCR filter is (uid=xyz) to fetch the person object.

However , when i run the LCR it gets failed, stating NULL pointer exception in View All Request.

Can someone explain why i am getting this error inspite of providing all 3 (person owner, service service, account account) to the extension

Answer (score 0):

If your LCR filter looking for Person try to create operation and LCR on entity level(**Person**).

Now with your LCR filter you are looking for accounts(not persons) with uid=xyz.